# Power/Sense line connections when a relay in path

Tags: power-supply, single-supply-op-amp

I need to connect a power supply instrument with (power and sense line) to my IC; this IC is separated by a relay.

Can I connect/tie the sense line of the instrument close to IC in the layout (as shown in figure 2)?

[image]

What would happen to the sense line when tied close to VCC pin and relay is open?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please [edit] your question to include a link to the IC datasheet. The answer depends on information in that. There's a built-in schematic tool button on the editor toolbar**. 
Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Thankyou.I checked the schematic tool, the Voltage source do not have sense lines in them. I have kelvin connection in my circuit. All the Source meters have sense lines to read back the voltage or current..

Answer (score 0):

In general, your second connection is a bad idea. Wit the switch open, the sense line will see 0V while the power supply is trying to regulate the power output. Unless the power supply is protected against a disconnected sense line (check your PS specifications), the power supply may try to raise the output voltage to bring the sense input up to the selected voltage and trigger an internal overvoltage shutdown or, in the extreme case, damage the power supply.

Comment: Thankyou, I was thinking when the relay is open or bad. the sense would read open. In this case off state voltage of the relay. So the PS should should not be affected it would show the clamp value that is programmed to. I believe the PS is protected but I will check again.